# HorizontalNavigation - NuxtUI - Passing data from a Pinia store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

I'm having an issue regarding the UHorizontalNavigation from NuxtUI.

When passing the "links" array to the "UHorizontalNavigation" component, it works.

However, I would like to deport the "links" array to a dedicated Pinia store.

When I do so, "UHorizontalNavigation" component is unable to display the icons anymore. Any clue ?

```js
// This works : 

<template>
  <UHorizontalNavigation :links="links"></UHorizontalNavigation>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
interface ILayoutState {
  icon?: string;
  label: string;
  to: string;
}

const links = [
  [
    {
      icon: 'i-heroicons-home-solid',
      label: 'Home',
      to: '/',
    },
    {
      icon: 'i-heroicons-book-open-solid',
      label: 'Product',
      to: '/product',
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      icon: 'i-heroicons-user-circle-solid',
      label: 'Login',
      to: '/login',
    },
  ],
] as ILayoutState[][];
</script>

// This doesn't work (only icons are not displayed) :

<template>
  <UHorizontalNavigation :links="links"></UHorizontalNavigation>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const layoutStore = useLayoutStore();
const links = computed(() => layoutStore.links);
</script>

// Below, is the store :

import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

interface ILayoutState {
  icon?: string;
  label: string;
  to: string;
}

export const useLayoutStore = defineStore('layoutStore', {
  state: () => ({
    links: [
      [
        {
          icon: 'i-heroicons-home-solid',
          label: 'Home',
          to: '/',
        },
        {
          icon: 'i-heroicons-book-open-solid',
          label: 'Product',
          to: '/product',
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          icon: 'i-heroicons-user-circle-solid',
          label: 'Login',
          to: '/login',
        },
      ],
    ] as ILayoutState[][],
  }),
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
});
```

Update : I was able to solve the issue by following this thread → #1450.

Should you encounter the same behavior as I did, simply add the following code snippet to your 'app.config.ts' file ↓

```
export default defineAppConfig({
  ui: {
    icons: {
      dynamic: true
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: the first parameter of `defineStore` is `string` instead of `StateTree`,  read the document [Interface: DefineSetupStoreOptions<Id, S, G, A>](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia.DefineSetupStoreOptions.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you suggesting that I extend my store using StateTree ? Unless I'm mistaken, I already use the id as a store parameter. The component works, except for the icons which are not displayed when I move the logic into the store.

Comment: I mean use `defineStore('layoutStore', {state: ...})` instead of  `defineStore({id: 'layoutStore', state: ...})`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've modified it and the problem is still there.